# Message: Undefined variable: data - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi guys I have this code and I am not sure what I am doing wrong, data is being defined as far as I can see, these are the errors I am getting:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: models/site_model.php

Line Number: 14
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/BLOCK/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 442
A Database Error Occurred

You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/BLOCK/models/site_model.php

Line Number: 14
```

controller:

```
<?php
class Site extends CI_Controller {

function index(){

    $this->load->view('option_view');
}

function create(){

    $data = array(
        'subject' => $this->input->post('subject'),
        'body' => $this->input->post('body')
    );

    $this->Site_model->add_record($data);
    $this->index();

}

}


?>
```

model:

```
<?php

class Site_model extends CI_Model {

function get_records()

{
    $query = $this->db->get('items');
    return $query->result();
}

function add_record()
{
    $this->db->insert('items', $data);
    $return;
}

function update_record()
{
    $this->db->where('id', 1);
    $this->db->update('items', $data);

}

function delete_record()
{
    $this->db->where('id', $this->url->segment(3));
    $this->db->delete('items');

}

}





?>
```

and the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<title>option_view</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
label {display:block;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Create</h2>
<?php echo form_open('site/create'); ?>

<p>
    </label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">
</p>

<p>
    </label for="body">Body</label>
    <input type="text" name="body" id="body">
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">    
</p>
<?php echo form_close();?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

What do you guys reckon?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method in your models aren't expecting a parameter. For example:

Change:

```
function add_record()
```

to:

```
function add_record($data)
```

Answer (score 3):

You never pass `$data` to your methods. This is a scope issue.

```
function add_record()
{
    $this->db->insert('items', $data);
    $return;
}
```

In this case, `add_record()` has no idea what `$data` is (and treats it as `null` because it hasn't been defined.

[Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0):

In these methods:

```
function add_record()
{
    $this->db->insert('items', $data);
    $return;
}

function update_record()
{
    $this->db->where('id', 1);
    $this->db->update('items', $data);

}
```

You have not passed data to the methods, so $data is undefined.