# Error Undefined variable: result + Error Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in CodeIgniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, error-handling, exception

Hi I was trying to place the `foreach` block in my view but i encountered 2 errors here :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: result
```

and

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Here is my view :

```
<?php foreach($result as $data_barang):?>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $data_barang->barang.kode_item;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data_barang->nama_item;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data_barang->nama_ruang;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data_barang->jml_item_kondisi;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data_barang->kondisi;?></td>
 </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

For addition i'll place the model and the controller here if it's needed :

controller :

```
public function index(){
    // load data barang yg akan ditampilkan
    $data['result']=$this->admin_model->get_data_table()->result_array();

    // load view
    $this->load->view('dashboard_admin');
}
```

*note : i also have tried with `->result()`

model :

```
function get_data_table(){
    $query_result = $this->db->query('SELECT barang.kode_item, nama_item, nama_ruang, jml_item_kondisi, kondisi 
        FROM barang 
        INNER JOIN info_barang ON barang.kode_item = info_barang.kode_item 
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ruang.nama_ruang, campur_table.kode_item 
            FROM ruang 
            INNER JOIN rekap_isi_ruang AS campur_table ON campur_table.nomor_ruang = ruang.nomor_ruang) AS barang_campur 
        ON barang.kode_item = barang_campur.kode_item');
    return $query_result;
}
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577968/php-codeigniter-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748324/message-undefined-variable-data-codeigniter) but still doesn't resolve my problems.

By the way, i'm sorry if there's any words that doesn't look familiar to you. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public function index(){
    // load data barang yg akan ditampilkan
    $data['result']=$this->admin_model->get_data_table()->result_array();

    // load view
    $this->load->view('dashboard_admin',$data);
}
```

Comment: thanks it works ! :) but unfortunately i have another errors and i think it's not relevant to my previous problem.. 'Message: Use of undefined constant kode_item - assumed 'kode_item' and 'Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$barang'.. it seems I have a problem with my query.. maybe I should post another question if i can't resolve it

Answer (score 1):

try this::
    // Controller

```
  public function index(){

        $data['result']=$this->admin_model->get_data_table()->result_array();


        $this->load->view('dashboard_admin',$data);
    }
```

// View

```
<?php
 if(!empty(result)) {
 foreach($result as $data_barang):?>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $data_barang->barang.kode_item;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data_barang->nama_item;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data_barang->nama_ruang;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data_barang->jml_item_kondisi;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data_barang->kondisi;?></td>
 </tr>
<?php

 endforeach;
} else { ?>
<tr>
  <td colspan="5">Some message here</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: thanks it works ! :) but unfortunately i have another errors and i think it's not relevant to my previous problem.. 'Message: Use of undefined constant kode_item - assumed 'kode_item' and 'Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$barang'.. it seems I have a problem with my query.. maybe I should post another question if i can't resolve it.. And sorry I can't upvote you for now

Answer (score 1):

Problem In Controller

You Store Data in $data['result'] variable but you not pass to View $data variable
so you pass $data variable in controller like this in controller

```
public function index(){
// load data barang yg akan ditampilkan
$data['result']=$this->admin_model->get_data_table()->result_array();

// load view
$this->load->view('dashboard_admin',$data);
}
```

this work fine

Comment: thanks it works ! :) but unfortunately i have another errors and i think it's not relevant to my previous problem.. 'Message: Use of undefined constant kode_item - assumed 'kode_item' and 'Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$barang'.. it seems I have a problem with my query.. maybe I should post another question if i can't resolve it.. And sorry I can't upvote you for now

Answer (score 1):

> Change your model into this

```
function get_data_table(){
    $query_result = $this->db->query('SELECT barang.kode_item, nama_item, nama_ruang, jml_item_kondisi, kondisi 
        FROM barang 
        INNER JOIN info_barang ON barang.kode_item = info_barang.kode_item 
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ruang.nama_ruang, campur_table.kode_item 
            FROM ruang 
            INNER JOIN rekap_isi_ruang AS campur_table ON campur_table.nomor_ruang = ruang.nomor_ruang) AS barang_campur 
        ON barang.kode_item = barang_campur.kode_item')->result();
    return $query_result;
}
```

If you want array use result_array() instead of query()->result();

Comment: thanks it works ! :) but unfortunately i have another errors and i think it's not relevant to my previous problem.. 'Message: Use of undefined constant kode_item - assumed 'kode_item' and 'Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$barang'.. it seems I have a problem with my query..
maybe I should post another question if i can't resolve it

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it works. We will find the solution for another issue for you .

Comment: If it is not relavant to this. I would like to suggest you to ask different question . U can find the solution first. It would be my pleasure to help you as well.

Comment: 'kode_item' and 'Message' fields are not selected in the query

Comment: You just retrieve the field in your query . Hope this is helpful to u

Comment: I've upvoted your question but unfortunately I have to earn 15 reputation points first before I can upvote you

Comment: Thanks . Please hit it when you get 15. Is your second problem solved by my answer in comments ?

Comment: Sure. :) ... I'm not sure about that. I'm still trying to figure it out.